# How can I more efficiently arrange my AXML layout?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I've been told that my XML layout is **horribly layered**. How else can I arrange it? Here's a picture of what I want my layout to look like:

[image]

Is it possible to place the image and **ImageButton**s in a single layout?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
    p1:layout_height="match_parent"
    p1:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    p1:background="@drawable/pickcitybackground">

  <RelativeLayout
      p1:minWidth="25px"
      p1:minHeight="25px"
      p1:layout_width="229.0dp"
      p1:layout_height="217.0dp"
      p1:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
      p1:paddingTop="90dp"
      p1:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        p1:src="@drawable/Pick"
        p1:layout_width="120dp"
        p1:layout_height="120dp"
        p1:id="@+id/pick"
        p1:background="#02ffffff"
        p1:scaleType="centerCrop" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    p1:minWidth="25px"
    p1:minHeight="25px"
    p1:layout_width="331.5dp"
    p1:layout_height="217dp"
    p1:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
    p1:paddingTop="90dp"
    p1:gravity="right">
    <ImageButton
        p1:src="@drawable/austinButton"
        p1:layout_width="120dp"
        p1:layout_height="120dp"
        p1:id="@+id/austinButton"
        p1:background="#02ffffff"
        p1:scaleType="centerCrop" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    p1:minWidth="25px"
    p1:minHeight="25px"
    p1:layout_width="229dp"
    p1:layout_height="match_parent"
    p1:id="@+id/relativeLayout4"
    p1:paddingTop="15dp"
    p1:gravity="center">
    <ImageButton
        p1:src="@drawable/nashvilleButton"
        p1:layout_width="120dp"
        p1:layout_height="120dp"
        p1:id="@+id/nashvilleButton"
        p1:scaleType="centerCrop"
        p1:background="#02ffffff" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    p1:minWidth="25px"
    p1:minHeight="25px"
    p1:layout_width="331.5dp"
    p1:layout_height="match_parent"
    p1:id="@+id/relativeLayout5"
    p1:gravity="right"
    p1:paddingTop="265dp">
    <ImageButton
        p1:src="@drawable/newyorkButton"
        p1:layout_width="120dp"
        p1:layout_height="120dp"
        p1:id="@+id/newyorkButton"
        p1:background="#02ffffff"
        p1:scaleType="centerCrop" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    p1:minWidth="25px"
    p1:minHeight="25px"
    p1:layout_width="229dp"
    p1:layout_height="match_parent"
    p1:id="@+id/relativeLayout6"
    p1:gravity="center"
    p1:paddingTop="350dp">
    <ImageButton
        p1:src="@drawable/sanfranButton"
        p1:layout_width="120dp"
        p1:layout_height="120dp"
        p1:id="@+id/sanfranButton"
        p1:background="#02ffffff"
        p1:scaleType="centerCrop" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    p1:minWidth="25px"
    p1:minHeight="25px"
    p1:layout_width="331.5dp"
    p1:layout_height="match_parent"
    p1:id="@+id/relativeLayout7"
    p1:gravity="right"
    p1:paddingTop="435dp">
    <ImageButton
        p1:src="@drawable/seattleButton"
        p1:layout_width="120dp"
        p1:layout_height="120dp"
        p1:id="@+id/seattleButton"
        p1:background="#02ffffff"
        p1:scaleType="centerCrop" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why did you choose using `p1:` instead of `android:`?

Comment: I used the Android Designer in Xamarin Studio and that's what it automatically used. What's the difference? I would like to know!

Comment: oww... I never use xamarin, but `android:` is the default convention in Java/Android Studio.

Comment: How about using GridLayout https://hackmd.io/CwDhAZgdgVhhaAnAQ3AZnsAxlYSQBmB8W4IyFMATAIwBsVBQA===?both ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I can see from here, is that you use relative layouts inside a relative layout. It should be possible to reduce your XML to only one relative layout.
Arrange your buttons using `android:layout_marginRight="10dp"` 
`android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"`
`android:layout_marginTop="10dp"`
`android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"`

Replace the "10dp" value with the one you need to.
Hope that helped

Comment: That helped. I didn't know I could control the placement of elements within the layout using the margin properties.

Comment: would you please mark this as the helping answer? :) glad it helped